# The Spring 4 WebSocket integrates into a Spring MVC application

Tags: spring, spring-mvc, jakarta-ee, spring-websocket

1. I write the simple web application based on `Spring MVC`. `Everything run Ok`. Then I create `Endpoint` and `HandShake` class to `Terminal (C# Application)` communicate with Server via `Websocket`.

   - **WebsocketEndPoint.java**:

     ```
     public class WebsocketEndPoint extends BinaryWebSocketHandler {

         @Override
         public void afterConnectionEstablished(WebSocketSession session) throws Exception {
             System.out.println("After Connection Established !!!!");
         }

         @Override
         protected void handleBinaryMessage(WebSocketSession session, BinaryMessage message) throws Exception {
             session.sendMessage(message);
         }

         @Override
         public void afterConnectionClosed(WebSocketSession session, CloseStatus closeStatus) throws Exception {
             System.out.println("After Connection Closed !!!!");
         }

     }
     ```
   - **HandshakeInterceptor.java**:

     ```
      public class HandshakeInterceptor extends HttpSessionHandshakeInterceptor{

         @Override
         public boolean beforeHandshake(ServerHttpRequest request,
             ServerHttpResponse response, WebSocketHandler wsHandler,
     Map<String, Object> attributes) throws Exception {
             System.out.println("Before Handshake");
             return super.beforeHandshake(request, response, wsHandler, attributes);
         }

         @Override
         public void afterHandshake(ServerHttpRequest request,
     ServerHttpResponse response, WebSocketHandler wsHandler, Exception ex) {
             System.out.println("After Handshake");
             super.afterHandshake(request, response, wsHandler, ex);
         }
     }
     ```
   - **XML to configure the websocket handler and interceptor** : websocketconfig.xml

     ```
     <beans xmlns="http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans"
         xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
         xmlns:websocket="http://www.springframework.org/schema/websocket"
         xsi:schemaLocation="
             http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans
             http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans/spring-beans.xsd
             http://www.springframework.org/schema/websocket
             http://www.springframework.org/schema/websocket/spring-websocket.xsd">

             <bean id="websocket" class="com.javahash.spring.WebsocketEndPoint"/>

             <websocket:handlers>
                 <websocket:mapping path="/PaymentHandler" handler="websocket"/>
                 <websocket:handshake-interceptors>
                 <bean class="com.javahash.spring.HandshakeInterceptor"/>
                 </websocket:handshake-interceptors>
             </websocket:handlers>
     </beans>
     ```
2. **Add websocketconfig.xml into Spring Application context**:

   - **web.xml**:

     ```
     <web-app xmlns="http://java.sun.com/xml/ns/j2ee"
         xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
         xsi:schemaLocation="http://java.sun.com/xml/ns/j2ee http://java.sun.com/xml/ns/j2ee/web-app_2_4.xsd"
         version="2.4">

         <display-name>Web server</display-name>

         <servlet>
             <servlet-name>webserver</servlet-name>
             <servlet-class>org.springframework.web.servlet.DispatcherServlet</servlet-class>
             <load-on-startup>1</load-on-startup>
         </servlet>

         <servlet-mapping>
             <servlet-name>dispatcher</servlet-name>
             <url-pattern>/</url-pattern>
         </servlet-mapping>

         <context-param>
             <param-name>contextConfigLocation</param-name>
             <param-value>
                 /WEB-INF/dispatcher-servlet.xml
                 /WEB-INF/websocketconf.xml
             </param-value>
         </context-param>

         <listener>
             <listener-class>org.springframework.web.context.ContextLoaderListener</listener-class>
         </listener>
     </web-app>
     ```
3. **After adding websocketconfig.xml into Spring Application context**:

   - Terminal (C# application) `can communicate with Server via Socket` but I `can not access web`.
   - I have `WARNING: No mapping found for HTTP request with URI [Spring4MVCHelloWorld/hello]] in DispatcherServlet with name 'dispatcher'`
   - **dispatcher-servlet.xml**:

     ```
     <beans xmlns="http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans"
      xmlns:context="http://www.springframework.org/schema/context"
      xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
      xsi:schemaLocation="
      http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans
      http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans/spring-beans-4.0.xsd
      http://www.springframework.org/schema/context
      http://www.springframework.org/schema/context/spring-context-4.0.xsd">

         <context:component-scan base-package="com.javahash.spring.controller" />

         <bean class="org.springframework.web.servlet.view.InternalResourceViewResolver">
             <property name="prefix">
                 <value>/WEB-INF/views/</value>
             </property>
             <property name="suffix">
                 <value>.jsp</value>
             </property>
         </bean>
     </beans>
     ```
   - **HelloWorldController.java**:

     ```
     package com.javahash.spring.controller;

     import org.springframework.stereotype.Controller;
     import org.springframework.ui.Model;
     import org.springframework.web.bind.annotation.RequestMapping;
     import org.springframework.web.bind.annotation.RequestParam;

     @Controller
     public class HelloWorldController { 

         @RequestMapping("/hello")
         public String hello(@RequestParam(value="name", required=false, defaultValue="World") String name, Model model) {
             model.addAttribute("name", name);
             return "helloworld";
         }

     }
     ```
   - It seems `@Controller not effect`.

Do i miss anything?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think you're missing `<mvc:annotation-driven/>` in your `dispatcher-servlet.xml` file. Spring scanned your Controller beans but Spring MVC did not register your mappings.